# Need to change SQL data to a NULL inside the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this stored procedure to retrieve data from a SQL database. Some of the data points are bad represented by -9999 or 9999, I would like to weed out the bad data and replace with a null value. Is there a way to do this inside this stored procedure?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
    FROM DataValues
    WHERE SiteID = 3 and VariableID IN (1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11)
     ) TableDate
PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1],[2],[4],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

Comment: Can you provide samples of the data and the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate DataValue there are many options.  If there are only two possible bad values you can use a case statement.  If there are more you can consider a 'control table' that you could join to.

Without sample data it is hard to be sure this will work but I think this is what you are looking to do.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], 
            CASE When DataValue = '-9999' Then null
                When DataValue = '9999' Then null
                Else DataValue
                End DataValue, VariableID
            FROM DataValues
            WHERE SiteID = 3 and VariableID IN (1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11)
         ) TableDate
    PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1],[2],[4],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

Answer (score 0):

Case works fine. as an another option, I would suggest you use NULLIF function

```
DataValue = NULLIF(NULLIF(DataValue, '-9999'), '9999')
```